# General Link Dialog "InsertLinkViaTreeDialog" misses InsertLinkRules after Upgrade to 8.2u2

Tags: rules-engine, speak

We recently upgraded from Sitecore 8.1u1 to Sitecore 8.2u2 and noticed that  the general link field dialog "**InsertLinkViaTreeDialog**" has a different structure now. We had a custom field that was populated by the "**InsertLinkButtonRuleDefinition**" Rule.

But now "InsertLinkButtonRuleDefinition" is missing and I can't figure out how the fields are populated. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sitecore 8.2u1

Previously `InsertLinkButton` values were populated with `InsertLinkButtonRule` (rule item id: `{CEDD4633-193B-4D79-8DCC-C49B3C8D0F53}`). Where **TargetControl** of this rule is `InsertLinkButton` and **Trigger** `click`

[image]

Action ID is `{D4BA15D6-263A-43E6-93DD-CE9E41C7D8E4}` and it still exists in **Sitecore 8.2u2** (`/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Layouts/Renderings/Resources/Rule/Rules/Actions/MakeInternalLinkFromTreeView`)

So you can use it if you want. I am not sure how your custom field works.

### Sitecore 8.2u2

Now there is no `InsertLinkButtonRule` rule which would populate button values. Instead, values are filled in JS.
If you open the `InsertLinkButton` button definition you will notice that click property (previously empty) now has following value in it:

```javascript
javascript:app.insertInternalLinkResult()
```

So you need to find a JS file. When you open **PageCode** rendering you will notice a path to the JS file.

[image]

After you open this file with a text editor you can see that there is an additional function called `insertInternalLinkResult`.

Code fragment:

```
  var itemLink = _.template(template, {
    displayText: htmlEncode(targetDisplayTextID.get("text")),
    alternateText: htmlEncode(targetAltTextID.get("text")),
    itemId: targetControlID.get("selectedItemId"),
    queryString: htmlEncode(targetQueryID.get("text")),
    target: targetWindowValue,
    styleClass: htmlEncode(targetStyleID.get("text")),
    path: path,
    anchor: htmlEncode(anchor.get("text"))
  });

  return this.closeDialog(itemLink);
```

Hope it helps.

p.s.

I used [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks) to analyse the dialog structure.

Comment: Where is this button found? InsertLinkButton.