# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format

Tags: speak

**FYI:** I've done a Express migration from 7.2 to 8.2, then upgraded to 8.2u1 -> u2.

When trying to Insert link on a link field i get this in the popup dialog:
 [image]

Before this i had another error similar to this, which I used the answer to proceed: [General Link Dialog "InsertLinkViaTreeDialog" misses InsertLinkRules after Upgrade to 8.2u2](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/general-link-dialog-insertlinkviatreedialog-misses-insertlinkrules-after-upgra/3800#3800)

After fixing this i got to the current problem.

> Value cannot be null

I cannot find any differences between a working copy of core.

Comment: if you press Clear buton and the insert link is working fine?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber - I tried, still same error.

Comment: @FilipJönsson check your log file there should be some specific error for same

Comment: I changed connString to an empty 8.2u2 core db and it resolves. But the Core DB that i used Express migration on from 7.2 -> 8.2 doesnt work. So now I know the error is in the migration tool from sitecore. Does the Core hold much more than users/roles etc? Maybe I can just add them manually?

Answer (score 1):

The Core Database holds all of the SPEAK UI items (and much more) needed to display various dialogue boxes.

If a Blank Core DB works, then put that DB back on and Package up the `/sitecore/client/Applications` node and deploy that on the previous database doing a overwrite. (Obviously back up your old core first in case you screw something up.)

[image: Core Database Items]

#### Applications

This Item and child items contain the content items needed to display the various applications that the Sitecore UI itself uses to display.  It is plausible that the issue resides here.  That is why I suggest packaging this folder.

#### Business Component Library

This is the commonly used set of SPEAK Renderings and Layouts. Items in the Applications depend on the Business Component Library items.  If packaging the Applications up doesn't fix the issue, you might try packaging up Business Component Library items instead.

#### Services and Speak

These two items contain more specific items that the Business Component Library and Applications depend on.  Based on this error, I don't expect the issue to lie in these sections.

### Why would this work?

SPEAK UI is configured, developed, and rendered based on items stored in the Core Database. These items are used by a large number of Sitecore's own client UI. SPEAK UI is a mix of Controller Renderings (defined in Core) combined with Javascript and CSS files stored in the file system under `/sitecore/shell/client/Applications` directory.

Due to your comment saying that the vanilla 8.2U2 core database works, I believe that the issue is the migration didn't properly copy over the proper elements needee in the Core database.

Therefore, packaging up the SPEAK UI items out of the vanilla Core DB and installing the package on your old Core DB using the Overwrite feature, will bring the appropriate items over that seem to be missing.

### Why package up all things?

Well, I take the line of thought that if one obscure item is out of whack, there might be others.  So to be safe, copy over all of the SPEAK UI client Application items.